# Linker error with libpng under MacOSX

Tags: xcode, macos, linker-errors, libpng

I'm working on MacOSX 10.7.2 and Xcode 4.2.1. I installed `libpng` using port and I was trying to load a PNG image in my application, but I get linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_png_create_read_struct", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_destroy_read_struct", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_init_io", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_set_sig_bytes", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_read_png", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_get_IHDR", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_get_rowbytes", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
  "_png_get_rows", referenced from:
      loadPngImage(char*, int&, int&, bool&, unsigned char**) in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I included `png.h` in my project using

```
#include "/usr/X11/include/png.h"
```

I know `libpng` is based on `zlib`, thus I have included `-lz` in "Other linker flags" but nothing changed.

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: At rough guess: looks like the 64 bit version is missing - have you tried `file` and `otool` on libpng?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved with a manual installation of `libpng`:

- download the source from [official web site](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)
- in Terminal, go in the downloaded folder and launch

  ```
  cp ./scripts/makefile.darwin makefile
  make 
  sudo make install
  make clean
  ```
- if it doesn't work (as in my case) open `makefile` with TextEdit (or equivalent) and change line

  `ARCH="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"`

  in

  `ARCH=-arch x86_64`

  (assuming, of course, your system is 64 bit).

It may not be enough. Xcode was still unable to find the library. I solved using

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s libpng15.dylib ./libpng15.15.dylib
```

That did the trick. Now it works fine.